# Iterate through properties of current context objects in Dust.js

Tags: dust.js

Given the JSON object:

```
errors =
{ 
  hashed_password: { 
     message: 'Validator "Password cannot be blank" failed for path hashed_password',
     name: 'ValidatorError',
     path: 'hashed_password',
     type: 'Password cannot be blank' },
  username: { 
     message: 'Validator "Username cannot be blank" failed for path username',
     name: 'ValidatorError',
     path: 'username',
     type: 'Username cannot be blank' },
  email: {
     message: 'Validator "Email cannot be blank" failed for path email',
     name: 'ValidatorError',
     path: 'email',
     type: 'Email cannot be blank' },
  name: { 
     message: 'Validator "Name cannot be blank" failed for path name',
     name: 'ValidatorError',
     path: 'name',
     type: 'Name cannot be blank' } 
}
```

How do I iterate through the properties of each "current context" object?

I would think you do something like this:

```
{#errors}
    {#.}
         {type}
    {/.}
{/errors}
```

Comment: Root issue: in what order would you want your output to be in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to iterate through members of an object in Dust. Part of the reason is that you cannot know the order of the members. Another part is that this is seen as bringing too much logic into Dust.

Instead, you can change the JSON to look more like this:

```
{
  errors: [
    {
      hashed_password: { 
        message: 'Validator "Password cannot be blank" failed for path hashed_password',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        path: 'hashed_password',
        type: 'Password cannot be blank'
      }
    },
    {
      username: { 
        message: 'Validator "Username cannot be blank" failed for path username',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        path: 'username',
        type: 'Username cannot be blank'
      }
    },
    {
      email: {
        message: 'Validator "Email cannot be blank" failed for path email',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        path: 'email',
        type: 'Email cannot be blank'
      }
    },
    {
      name: { 
        message: 'Validator "Name cannot be blank" failed for path name',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        path: 'name',
        type: 'Name cannot be blank'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: So could you site a snippet of the most efficient way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

If you really have to put meaningful data into object keys, consider writing a contextual helper, as per:

- https://github.com/akdubya/dustjs/issues/9
- [Dust.js output JSON key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564997/dust-js-output-json-key)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over an object using a helper.

For example, you could define a helper like this one:

```js
dust.helpers.iter = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  var obj = dust.helpers.tap(params.obj, chunk, context);

  var iterable = [];

  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var value = obj[key];

      iterable.push({
        '$key': key,
        '$value': value,
        '$type': typeof value
      });
    }
  }

  return chunk.section(iterable, context, bodies);
};
```

Then, in your template, you would loop through like this:

```
{@iter obj=errors}
  {$value.type}
{/iter}
```

Comment: Although that technically works, keep in mind that the order the elements will be rendered in is not defined, and might even change every time you render the template. You might want to build the list of keys into an array, sort it and only then iterate on that.